# Flutter error: 'NoSuchMethodError. The Method [] was called on null'

Tags: flutter, spoonacular

Im currently designing a 'whats in my fridge' style application for college. The first page Ive started on is the recipes page. I wish for it to retrieve the recipes from this API (Spoonacular.com) and simply display them on the recipe page. Im having trouble with this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**RECIPE.API.DART FILE**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:best_before/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:best_before/models/recipe.dart';


class RecipeApi{
  static Future<List<Recipe>> getRecipe() async{
    var uri = Uri.https('spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com', '/recipes/search',
        {'query': 'burger','diet': 'vegetarian','excludeIngredients': 'coconut','intolerances': 'egg, gluten','number': '10','offset': '0','type': 'main course'});

    final response = await http.get(uri,headers:{
      'x-rapidapi-host': 'spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
      'x-rapidapi-key': 'API KEY',
      'useQueryString':'true'
    });

  Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
  List _temp = [];

    for (var i in data['results']){
      _temp.add(i['0']);
    }

    return RecipeList.recipesFromSnapshot(_temp);
}

}
```

**RECIPE.DART FILE**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Recipe{
  final String name;
  final String images;
  final String id;
  final String readyInMinutes;
    Recipe({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.images,
    @required this.id,
    @required this.readyInMinutes,
  });

  //Recipe({this.name, this.id, this.totalTime});

  factory Recipe.fromJson(dynamic json){
    return Recipe(
      name: json['title'] ?? '',
       id: json['id'].toString(),
      images: 
      "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/${json['id']}-556x370.${json['imageType']}",
      readyInMinutes: json['readyInMinutes'].toString(),
    );
  }
}

class RecipeList {
  final List<Recipe> list;
    RecipeList ({
      @required this.list,
    });
  
  factory RecipeList.fromJson (List<dynamic> json) {
    return RecipeList(
      list: json.map((data) => Recipe.fromJson(data)).toList(),
    );
  }

   static List<Recipe> recipesFromSnapshot(List snapshot){
     return snapshot.map(
     (data){
         return Recipe.fromJson(data);
       }).toList();
   } 
  @override
     String toString(){
       return 'Recipe {name, images, id, readyInMinutes}';
     }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have a few things to say:

First I ask you to please put your code in your future questions instead of linking to a github repository, this makes it easier for us to see the code and that makes it more likely for you to get an answer.

Second, your problem, it happens because on the `recipe.api.dart` file, you commented out line 23, meaning the `getRecipe` method returns null, making your recipes on your recipes page null aswell.

Finally, I know nothing about the spoonacular.com API, but if it works like most other APIs, your API key should be private. You should not put it into a public repository for the world to see, unless you want to get DDOS'd (as I said, I don't know anything about spoontacular, but unless explicitly stated otherwise, I would assume you shouldn't share this key)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I made the API key mistake and believe its since been updated. I do apologise, I thought it was easier to use git links but thank you for the heads up! Ive since uncommented that line and now facing another error :(

Comment: Happy to help you! I see you already posted a new question and you even already got an answer!

Comment: I did haha! Determined to get this page working! However Ive now returned back to this same method null error! I appear to be stuck in a loop :( coding problems!